# Master index updated even though manual strategy is set

Tags: solr, content-search, indexing

I have changed update strategy for Master database to be "manual" rather than "sync", which to my understanding should not update "master" when data changes in master database. I can see in crawling log that strategy is initiated properly:

`[Index=sitecore_master_index] Initializing ManualStrategy. Index will have to be rebuilt manually`

However, I can see in the logs the following:

`Starting update of index for the database 'master' (6 pending).
Update of index for the database 'master' done.`

Am I missing something or that's something normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing a **Content Search** index (which indeed you have disabled) with legacy **Sitecore.Search** database indexes which apparently are still working.

In order to disable Sitecore Legacy indexes you should set the following setting values:

```
<setting name="Indexing.UpdateInterval" value="00:00:00"/>
<setting name="Indexing.Enabled" value="false" />
```

Also you have to remove `<indexes>` definitions for each `<database>` definition.

It can be done by removing **master** and **core** nodes from index locations under the `/configuration/sitecore/search/configuration/indexes/index/locations` node in the **Sitecore.config**

Answer (score 2):

I have changed my local instance's master index strategy & even I see similar logs

```
<DATETIME> INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
ManagedPoolThread <DATETIME> INFO  Starting update of index for the database 'master' (3 pending).
ManagedPoolThread <DATETIME> INFO  Update of index for the database 'master' done.
```

But I went ahead & tried to search the recently added item from the content editor, the item didn't turn up :)
I probably think that's the normal behavior & doesn't mean that indexing is actually done for the item that has been added recently. Sitecore by default logs an entry that it processed the strategy that has been configured & doesn't actually index the item :)